# Извлечь корень из отрицательного числа

Tags: c#

Как извлечь корень из отрицательного числа? Например, результатом выражения `Math.Pow(-8, 1.0/3)` будет `NaN`, хотя должно быть `-2`.

Comment: извлеките из положительного и добавьте минус :)

Comment: А если степень будет `1.0/4` ?

Comment: учите мат анализ! :) Берете корень от модуля, и учитываете img часть, т.е. корень из -1 равен плюс минус i, если мене память не изменяет:)

Comment: Формально `1.0/3` не равно `1/3` (пусть разница и мала, но она есть). А потому результат `NaN` формально абсолютно верен.

Comment: Почему 2? `-2` же.. Питон, к слову умеет. Вероятно, потому что у него есть понятие рациональных дробей...

Answer (score 14):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.7.1#remarks), при конечном отрицательном основании и конечном нецелом показателе результат равен `NaN`. Это значит, что `Math.Pow` ведёт себя не совсем так, как стандартная математическая степень, и вам придётся самим обрабатывать случай отрицательного основания.

---

Почему так сделано? Думаю, потому, что дроби наподобие 1/3 нельзя представить точно значением типа `double`. Поскольку в случае чётного знаменателя результат получается комплексным, мы видим, что малая ошибка в показатели степени ведёт к большой ошибке в результате. Поэтому разумным было бы просто не пытаться подсчитать результат для таких вот случаев.

---

Хорошо, а как решать задачу по извлечению корня целой степени? Ну просто анализируйте знак.

```
int rootpower = 3;
double value = -8;

int sign = Math.Sign(value);
double absRoot = Math.Pow(Math.Abs(value), 1.0/rootpower);

if (rootpower % 2 == 0 && sign == -1)
{
    Complex root = Complex.ImaginaryOne * absRoot;
    // результат комплексный, работайте с ним
}
else
{
    double root = sign * absRoot;
    // результат действительный, работайте с ним
}
```

Comment: Шестая строчка в таблице секции **Remarks** по ссылке.

Comment: Я не спрашивал, почему так сделано, и представляю, как хранится 1/3 в значении типа double. По сути, извлечение корня нечетной степени из отрицательного числа - элементарное дело, однако, например, C# и Wolphram не могут справиться с такой задачей. Меня интересует именно то, как решается эта задача. И что значит "просто не пытаться подсчитать результат для таких вот случаев", если есть необходимость в этом?

Comment: @mtrfnv: Тогда вы должны понимать, что 1/3 округляется до числа с чётным знаменателем, и формальный результат был бы комплексным. А решать задачу просто: убирайте знак, потом возвращайте.

Comment: @mtrfnv Я полагаю, Wolfram Mathematica  "не справляется" с вычислением кубического корня из отрицательного числа из-за того, что по какой-то причине считает основным корнем один из его мнимых корней (связанная тема: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/cubic-root-of-negative-numbers)

Comment: *"Это значит, что Math.Pow ведёт себя не совсем так, как стандартная математическая степень"* - вот это не совсем верно. Просто под записью "стандартной математической степени" скрывается несколько принципиально разных функций, и Math.Pow реализует не все из них.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Пожалуй, вы правы. Но реализовать _все_ было бы очень проблематично, думаю.

Answer (score 11):

> интересует именно то, как решается эта задача

```
double Root(double base, int degree)
{
  if (base < 0 && degree % 2 == 1)
    return -Math.Pow(Math.Abs(base), 1.0 / degree);
  else 
    return Math.Pow(base, 1.0 / degree);
}
```

Comment: Ещё стоит рассмотреть случай чётной степени корня. Например, `Root(-1, 2)` должно давать `i`.

Comment: @VladD Kонечно. У меня сложилось впечатление, что остальные случаи, описанные в таблице документации, автора вопроса устраивают.

Answer (score 7):

Отрицательные числа имеют 3 кубических корня: один действительный (отрицательный) и два мнимых, с одинаковым комплексным модулем. Число 2 не является кубическим корнем из -8, это значение комплексного модуля для его корней. Если вам нужно найти его действительный корень (-2), используйте комплексную арифметику:

```
var result = - System.Numerics.Complex.Pow(-8, 1.0 / 3).Magnitude;
```