# NaN при работе с классом Math

Tags: c#, математика, nan

Почему-то в выходе переменная otvet = NaN , отладчик ничего не хочет объяснять.

```
double x = 45;
double y = 45;
double otvet = Math.Pow((1 - Math.Tan(x)), (Math.Cos(x)/Math.Sin(x)));
otvet += Math.Cos(x - y);
```

Как уже заметили при x = 0,1 и y = 0,1 NaN не будет

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Может деление на 0? Или какая нибудь другая не разрешённая операция.

Comment: Спорим, если ввести `0.1` и `0.1` - будет не `NaN`?

Comment: А если ввести 45 и 45 ошибка, а должно единицу вывести

Comment: Может, все-таки прочитать про тригонометрические функции в C#, что они принимают в качестве аргумента, и чем радианы отличаются от градусов?

Comment: Игорь, потому что вот https://imgur.com/a/2Ols4fV , сейчас почитаю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Извлечь корень из отрицательного числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865721/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: Я думаю глупо считать дубликатом, тк. ответ кроется в том числе в градусах и радианах

Comment: @КоноваловМаксим тригонометрические функции цикличны. Поэтому ошибка в использовании градусов вместо радианов конечно имеет место и сбила меня с толку, но она может привести только к неверным результатам вычислений, но не может приводить к NaN. Проблема именно в особенностях Math.Pow. В целом вам конечно следовало самостоятельно выяснить на каком именно этапе вычислений  вас появляется NaN, это не так уж сложно, просто вынести результаты вычисления каждой функции в отдельные переменные и использовать их в дальнейших вычислениях. Это один из стандартных приемов локализации ошибок.

Answer (score 3):

тригонометрические функции в C# принимают в качестве аргумента радианы, a радианы отличаются от градусов в `Math.PI/180` раз:

```
double otvet = Math.Pow(1 - Math.Tan(x * Math.PI / 180), Math.Cos(x * Math.PI / 180) / Math.Sin(x * Math.PI / 180));
otvet += Math.Cos((x - y) * Math.PI / 180);
```

Comment: Может, добавите немного текста? Чтобы не строить diff с кодом из вопроса в уме :)

Comment: Боюсь, теперь у автора возникнет вопрос, почему NaN получается при x = 50. :)

Comment: @tym32167 только для Вас )

Comment: @Yaant https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865721

Comment: @Igor imho, вот как раз эта ссылка и дает настоящий ответ на исходный вопрос. А градусы там или радианы - дело десятое :)

Comment: @Yaant Поверите, сначала проголосовал за закрытие как дубликат этого вопроса, а потом засомневался и убрал?

Comment: @Igor Охотно верю. :)