# NaN при табуляции функции

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string temp;
            double y,a, x, k,max,dx;
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ConsoleApp5/ConsoleApp5/date.txt");
            temp = streamReader.ReadLine();
            a=Convert.ToDouble(temp);
            temp = streamReader.ReadLine();
            k=Convert.ToDouble(temp);
            temp = streamReader.ReadLine();
            x =Convert.ToDouble(temp);
            temp = streamReader.ReadLine();
            max =Convert.ToDouble(temp);
            temp = streamReader.ReadLine();
            dx = Convert.ToDouble(temp);

            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("./result.txt");
            for (double i = x; i < max; i+=dx,x+=dx)
            {
                if (Math.Log(a * x)>0 )
                {
                    y = (Math.Pow(Math.Cos(a * x), 1.0/3.0)) + (k * Math.Cos(a * x) / Math.Log(a * x));
                    streamWriter.Write("\t {0:N3}", y);
                }

            }

            streamWriter.Close();

            streamReader.Close();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Данные в файл записаны вот так (в столбик):

> 2,3
>   15,2
>   11,13
>   22,23
>   0,5

Вывод в файле:

> 5,150   NaN     NaN     NaN     2,248   5,401   2,823   NaN     NaN     NaN     4,409   4,504   NaN     NaN     NaN     2,465   5,016   2,301   NaN     NaN     NaN     4,337   4,048

Откуда берётся NaN?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас там нету деления на 0? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.nan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Зачем вам две одинаковые переменные (`i` и `x`)?

Comment: [было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865721/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0);
дробная степень это корень => разрешить неоднозначность на бумажке вынеся множитель **-1** => ни в коем случае не выбрасывать вариант`Math.Cos(a * x) < 0`, а считать `Math.Pow(...)` как для положительного, не забывая домножить результат на **-1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cos(ax)` становится отрицательным (`-0.93` для данных на картинке), и `Math.Pow(double x, double y);` [не может возвести в дробную степень](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> x < 0, но не NegativeInfinity; y не является целым числом,
>   NegativeInfinity, или PositiveInfinity.
>
> Возвращаемое значение  NaN

P.S. У вас случайно не подразумеваются значения `a*x` в градусах?

Comment: Тоесть мне нужно сделать проверку что бы косинус не был отрицательным? по поводу градусов - велечина не указана просто числа

Comment: Сделал проверку на cos >0 результаты с NaN пропали :)

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh если это и правда табуляция функции - вам нельзя выкидывать значения

Comment: Проверьте, что будет при переводе `a*x` из градусов в радианы - всё ли уложится в диапазон. Про выбрасывание значений - уже сказали, что это неправильно.